# Default Trusted root certification authorities for a new Microsoft Windows installation

Tags: windows, https, certificate, ssl-certificate, digital-certificate

My understanding is that a brand new installation of Microsoft Windows [10]  comes with a default set of Certificate root authorities. Where can I view that list?

For instance in the case apple it is the following:

[List of available trusted root certificates in macOS High Sierra](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208127)

or in the case of browsers we have the following:

http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/certs/included/

Where can we get the default list for Windows 10? Is this list the same for other editions of Windows( Server versions for instance)?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you found a list; however, Microsoft publishes their yearly participant list here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/trusted-root/participants-list

This is how I found a similar answer.